# Regex to return all/multiple matches by ignoring specific match in between the required groups

Tags: python, regex, search, nested, match

I want a regex for below text:

```
 \editable[blab]{\textit{anna karenina}}
```

Here, `\editable` will be common, so we need to add that keyword in regex.
I want the content inside the square bracket as match 1 and inside the curly braces as match 2.

I also have a condition that it may have multiple curly braces, so we can add a condition like after curly braces start it should not be a `\` and, if not, consider those curly braces and return the value inside.

So, in my case, my values will be:

```
Blah
anna karenina
```

I tried multiple regexes, including the one below, but they didn't work.

```
 r"\\editable\[(.*?)\]{\\.*\{(.*?)\}}"
```

This is working for my requirement but it does not return all matches in the text; it returns only one.

Comment: Show your own effort (regex) as properly formatted text in the question even if it didn't work.

Comment: r"\[([^\[\]\{\}]*(?:\\editable)\s\{)(.*?)\}"

Tried this one and many more as well

Comment: Which regex did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [this regex](https://regexr.com/7k3i4),

```
\\editable\[(.*?)\]{\\.*\{(.*?)\}}
```

Code:

```
text = "\\editable[blab]{\\textit{anna karenina}}"
pattern = r"\\editable\[(.*?)\]{\\.*\{(.*?)\}}"
match = re.search(pattern, text)

print(match.group(1))
print(match.group(2))
```

---

**Output:**

```
blab
anna karenina
```

**Update-1:**

To handle the text with multiple patterns,

```
import re

text = "\\editable[blab]{\\textit{anna karenina}} and \\editable[another]{\\xyz{some example}}"

pattern = r"\\editable\[(.*?)\]{\\(?:.*?)\{(.*?)\}}"
results = re.findall(pattern, text)

for result in results:
    square_bracket_content, flower_bracket_content = result
    print("Square bracket content:", square_bracket_content)
    print("flower bracket content:", flower_bracket_content)
```

---

**Output:**

```
Square bracket content: blab
flower bracket content: anna karenina
Square bracket content: another
flower bracket content: some example
```

Comment: \textit will not be fixed there may be anything
Like \bold{\bah{mytext}} likewise

Comment: Tried but not giving any match

Comment: How are you trying? Can you share the code by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77098969/edit)ing your post?

Comment: Tried and it is working

Comment: I have one more issue as if my text contains multiple such pattern what to do?

Comment: I have 2 scenario 

1. \\editable[header_top_right]{\\textit{fgh kdfkcfsd}}

2. \\editable[header_top_left]{anna karenina}


if {\ then it look for { only and return value if {\ not there then return {value} directly

Comment: my sample text is like this 

"\\begin{document}\r\n\\maketitle\r\n\\tableofcontents\r\n\r\n\r\n{{ content }}\r\n\r\n{{ bib }}\r\n\r\n\\editable[header_top_left]{anna karenina}\r\n\\editable[header_top_right]{\\textit{fgh kdfkcfsd}}\r\n\\\\\r\n\\editablegraphics[signature_logo]{pict1.png}\r\n\\editablegraphics[other_logo]{}\r\n\\editablegraphics[logo]{}\r\n\r\n\\end{document}"

my output will be

header_top_left
anna karenina

header_top_right
fgh kdfkcfsd

Comment: @KomalRumade Please be clear, your first text shows `...\\editable[header_top_left]{\textit{anna karenina}}...`, current one is `...\\editable[header_top_left]{anna karenina}...` , which one is correct?, why textit(or blah) is missing?